# uso de estados de un componente en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const [numClics, setNumClics] = useState(0)
```

estoy trabajando con estados de un componente en React y tenia una duda que no he podido solventar, los estados empiezan con un valor determinado y luego sufren mutaciones con el tiempo que son desencadenas por eventos que el usuario hace. Ahora en este caso estoy usando un estado para cambiar el numero de clics, entonces en pocas palabras numClics = seria la accion y setNumClics la accion que se producira en el estado y el valor en useState seria el valor determinado inicial en el que se empezara?
si alguien puede aclararme la duda con ejemplos seria de gran ayuda

Comment: `numClics` es el valor actual y `setNumClics` es la funcion que debes ejecutar si deseas cambiar ese valor por otro... por ejemplo `setNumClics(80)` para que ahora `numClics` almacene 80

Comment: ok chevere muchas gracias @Pipe buena tu explicacion, aplica para cualquier otro estado no relacionado a cambiar clics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {useState} from 'react';
//Valor inicial = 0
const [numClics, setNumClics] = useState(0)
//Incrementa en uno numClics
setNumClics(numClics+1)//numClicks = 0+1...(valor inicial)+1
//accediendo a numClics  

return(   <p>numero de clicks{numClics}</p> )
```

Al declarar la variable de estado le pasa un valor por defecto que en este caso es 0, para modificar la variable tienes que usar la funcion setNumClics para actualizar el valor de esta, como el ejemplo de arriba.. puedes usar directamente la variable de estado como se muestra en el return.

Te dejo la documentacion de useState en el siguiente enlace:[Doc useState React](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: ooh okay muchas gracias por explicarme, ya reviso la documentacion! @David081